# Perturbative QCD application in FAIR

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, perturbation-theory

In [FAIR CBM](https://www-alt.gsi.de/forschung/fair_experiments/CBM/LOI2004v6.pdf) scenario i.e at high density will be perturbative QCD applicable?

Answer (score 1):

PQCD is only applicable at really high energy and FAIR CBM experiment will have quite low energy and finite baryonic density. 
As it is said on the official doc :
http://www.fair-center.eu/fileadmin/fair/publications_FAIR/FAIR_BTR_3a.pdf

Low energy model will be available to compare data, but in my opinion, lattice QCD is the best tool available to discuss results at FAIR and to probe the phase transition between hadronic matter and the QGP.
However, it might still be possible to use pQCD for some initial collision and to try to understand energy loss mechanisms at finite density.

Answer (score 0):

> [Perturbative QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbative_QCD)  is a subfield of particle physics in which the theory of strong interactions, Quantum Chromodynamics (QCD), is studied by using the fact that the strong coupling constant $\alpha_s$ is small in high energy or short distance interactions, thus allowing Perturbation theory techniques to be applied

It has been used for high energies, and is projected to be used in ultra relativistic ion collisions. Google  *ion ion collisions and perturbative QCD* and a number of articles appear. The answer by JSFDude covers the  case of CBM . The energies of [1-15 GeV antiprotons](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0804/0804.0177.pdf)  are too low to allow QCD studies with perturbative techniques.

Comment: Although there might be applications of perturbative QCD for some observables, the [physics case of CBM](http://www.fair-center.eu/for-users/experiments/nuclear-matter-physics/cbm/introduction.html) looks to me that it is highly focused on non-perturbative QCD.

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis  CBM  is not in the range of perturbative QCD, nor they are claiming it, nor have I used it as  an exampl. It is the next answer that is talking aboud FAIR and CBM .  For perturbative QCD see  an example https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1318

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis  reviewed my answer and changed it. It was very hard to find the energies at FAIR!!!

Comment: Well, perturbative QCD was my turf in a previous life! So I know about how it can be used at LHC ;-)